# Is it possible to fire a modal when the user attempts to close the browser with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

like says my title...

Is it possible to fire a modal when the user attempts to close the browser with AngularJS? I need to show the modal for the user to fill out a survey.

If that is possible, have u some tuto? I have trying the next code in my controller, but displays a confirm window.

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
var message = 'If you leave this page you are going to lose all unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?';
if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
event = $window.event;
}

return message;
};
```

Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beforeunload` is a [browser standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload). Whatever you return from the function is the message that displays in the confirmation dialog before closing the window.

If you're using a browser that complies to this standard like Firefox, Chrome, or IE, you won't be able to hijack the native behaviour. So, your confirmation message should be persuasive enough for the user to want to stay on your site.